# Prevent scrolling when changing TextEditingController text flutter

Tags: flutter

Iam using  TextEditingController control and when I set the control text to a new data by using `control.text = 'hi';`
in a function, the listview scroll to the widget which use this control because the data has been changed.

How to prevent scrolling the widget which use this control when I change the control text and stay in the same position in the screen?

```
Widget textbox_widget1(){
         return TextFormField(
          keyboardType: TextInputType.number, 
          controller: control, 
          autofocus: false,
        );
}
```

and here I added my listview in a scaffold in build function

```
     child: Scrollbar(
                controller: _scrollController,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only( bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom / 1.5), // fixade keyboard över title med padding, 1.5 ta bort vit padding
                  child: ListView(
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                    children: <Widget>[

                      SizedBox(height: 15.0),

                      textbox_widget1(),

                      SizedBox(height: 15.0),

                      textbox_widget2(),

                     SizedBox(height: 15.0),

                      textbox_widget3(),

            SizedBox(height: 15.0),

              textbox_widget4(),

            textbox_widget5(),
                      SizedBox(hight: 70,),


                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

and the function is something like this

```
    void set_text(){control.text = 'new data';}
```

Thanks

Comment: I added the listview

Comment: I think you should use the `physics` with the condition to `ListView` to prevent scrolling while usage.

Comment: I cannot use   physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), because it will prevent the user to scroll down

Comment: Iam thinking why it scroll to the TextFormField widget which use this control ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by using TextEditingController

```
control = new TextEditingController(text: 'new value');
```